# Values method of JS Set

Tags: javascript

`.values()` method of Javascript `Set`

`.values()` method returns a new iterator object where we can access all the elements / values. But I am just using `for..of` loop function to access elements of `Set` without using `.values()`. Here is the code:

```js
const letters = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);

for (x of letters) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Is both similar or is there any difference? I am beginner.. Also why to use `.values()` method instead of `for..of` loop if both are same?

Comment: A loop is never the same as an iterator. The `for...of` loop uses an iterator to step through the elements of the collection.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. If you ask a question you should/have to be precise. In this case it's not really problem (because `Set` is a built-in type, and `.values()` a built-in method of that type) but keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: In this case there's no significant difference between `for (x of letters)` and `for (x of letters.values())`. The `values()` method is useful for consistency with other containers like `Map`.